# Run my integration tests with a different *.properties file using Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am currently using **Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE** and have the following Spring configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:config.properties"})
public class MyServiceConfig {
...
```

I was wondering if there is a way to run integration tests for my component-annotated-classes with a different properties file (let's say `test-config.properties`) in order to give different values for my value and autowired annotated properties and methods.

**NOTE:** I know that **Spring 4.1.x** comes with `@TestPropertySource` which helps to achieve it. But upgrading Spring to later versions is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Specify "profile" for integration tests.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:test-config.properties"})
@Profile("integration-test")
public class MyServiceTestConfig {
...
```

In order to use this profile when testing repository use `@ActiveProfiles` annotation

```
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyRepositoryTest {
...
```

Comment: Does that mean that I should create another Spring configuration file for testing purposes? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Branislav for answering, but is it possible to to avoid creating a test  configuration file?

Comment: @leo.fcx Maybe it is. But I was never using same configuration (read: database) for integration tests and for production code.